# File open error by using codec utf-8 in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I execute following code on windows xp and python 2.6.4

But it show IOError.

How to open file whose name has utf-8 codec.

```
>>> open( unicode('한글.txt', 'euc-kr').encode('utf-8') )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    open( unicode('한글.txt', 'euc-kr').encode('utf-8') )
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80.txt'
```

But the following code to the normal operation.

```
>>> open( unicode('한글.txt', 'euc-kr') )
<open file u'\ud55c\uae00.txt', mode 'r' at 0x01DD63E0>
```

Comment: I think Windows uses UTF-16 for encoding the filenames.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C runtime interface that Windows exposes to Python uses the system code page to encode filenames. Unlike on OS X and modern Linux versions, on Windows the system code page is never UTF-8. So the UTF-8 byte string won't be any good.

You could encode the filename to the current code page using `.encode('mbcs')`, which in your case is probably equivalent to `.encode('cp949')`. To make it compatible with other platforms where filenames are UTF-8, you could look up `sys.getfilesystemencoding`, which will give you `utf-8` there or `mbcs` on Windows.

However whilst `cp949` would work for Korean characters, it would break on anything outside the repertoire of that code page (an extended version of EUC-KR).

So another approach is to keep your filenames as Unicode. On Windows this will use the Unicode-native interfaces to pass filenames to Windows in the UTF-16LE encoding it uses internally. (See [PEP277](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0277/) for more on this feature.)

This does generally still work on other platforms too: Linux and OS X should silently encode the Unicode filenames to UTF-8 for you. This may fail more in older Python versions, but it's the default way to handle filenames in Python 3 (where the default string type has changed to Unicode).

The traps to watch out for with using Unicode filenames on Python 2 are:

- if [os.path.supports_unicode_filenames](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.supports_unicode_filenames) is False, as it will be outside Windows, the functions that return filenames, such as `os.listdir`, will always give you byte strings. You'd have to detect that and decode them using `sys.getfilesystemencoding`.
- if you have a file on Linux/OS X with a name that's not a valid UTF-8 string, you won't be able to get a Unicode filename for it (UnicodeDecodeError if you try). Bit of a corner case, but it can lead to annoying inaccessible files.

Incidentally,

```
open(unicode('한글.txt', 'euc-kr'))
```

Probably you would want to say `'cp949'` there (as the Windows Korean code page has minor differences to EUC-KR). Or, more generally, `'mbcs'`, which gives you the system code page which is presumably going to be the same one your console is typing. Anyway, I don't know about PyShell, but normally if the above works then you should just be able to type it directly:

```
open(u'한글')
```

Comment: Yeah... it is, sadly, still a bit of a headache. Python 3 improves on this a bit.

Comment: +1 It seems that you have a lot of time and patience to explain things.

Comment: Actually, Windows can have UTF-8 as the system encoding (chcp 65001), but most applications will misbehave.