# Using python 2.7, why does my unicode filename raise an IOError when calling file() on it?

Tags: python, file, unicode, file-io, ioerror

Python 2.7:

I am trying to open an mp3 to read its ID3 tag using mutagen (so I'd rather not have to change the method), which calls:

```
file(filename, "rb")
```

For files with no special characters this works fine, but otherwise, I sometimes seem to get

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u"somepath\\08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\x9cur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3"
```

while other times

```
u"somepath\\02 - Max\xefmo Park - Apply Some Pressure.mp3"
```

works fine.

What's the difference between the two? Why does one work while the other doesn't?

Cheers,

Felix

EDIT: It worked when running under pydev in Eclipse, for which

```
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

returned "Cp1252" but not from the command line which returned "ascii". The filename when printed to the Eclipse console was

```
u"somepath\\08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\u0153ur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3"
```

EDIT: The code which gets the filename from Winamp (the music player) is:

```
winampProcess = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, False, processID)
memoryBuffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(winampProcess.handle, memoryPointer, memoryBuffer, 256, 0)
winampProcess.Close()
rawPath = win32api.GetFullPathName(memoryBuffer.raw.split("\x00")[0])
try:
    unicodeString = unicode(rawPath)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    unicodeString = u""
    for char in rawPath:
        try:
            unicodeString += unicode(char)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as err:
            errStr = str(err)
            startIndex = errStr.index("0x")
            endIndex = errStr.index(" ", startIndex)
            hexStr = ""
            for i in range(startIndex, endIndex):
                hexStr += errStr[i]
            unicodeString += unichr(int(hexStr, 16))
return unicodeString
```

EDIT: The problem is fixed if I explicitly set

```
unicode(str, "cp1252")
```

but I still don't understand what causes the problem, and this is a hacky fix that probably won't work for other dodgy filenames...

Comment: Help us to help you, show us some code ;)

Comment: This is on Vista, btw, but I need my code to be portable.

Comment: I'm not sure what more is needed...?

Comment: Where does "filename" come from?

Comment: About making your code portable: once you start involving the file system and directory structure, things get hairy. Use the "os.path" module to construct pathnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing - you're pulling the filename from a program which is using a multibyte character set in the current default encoding, which is cp1252 for English versions of Windows. Ascii doesn't include *any* extended characters, which is why you get the error when you try to encode the string into Unicode using the Ascii encoding.

Edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737410/file-open-error-by-using-codec-utf-8-in-python/1737476#1737476) has some information about encoding file names in the current Windows code page.

Comment: Is there any way to tell which encoding was used by Winamp (the program I'm pulling the filename from), or if I simply use "mbcs", will that always work? The convertion to unicode is actually a separate function that is used by different modules for different OSes e.g. XMMS for FreeBSD, so if I only change that, should it still work across platforms?

Comment: Mark is correct, Winamp uses cp1521, which is the default in Windows. In fact, it probably doesn't use any encoding at all, but just returns the filename as it gets it from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use os.listdir() on the directory to see what the filename is, encoded. Then compare that to what you get when you do filename.encode('cp1252'). There should be a difference, and that should tell you what is wrong.

The only real problem I can think of is that something gets decoded twice. You could have normalization problems too, but that seems unlikely in this case.

Comment: Ok, so os.listdir("somepath") gives "08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\x9cur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3", os.listdir(u"somepath") gives u"08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\u0153ur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3", and filename.encode("cp1252") raises UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x9c' in position 76: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: OK, \x9c is quite correctly an œ in cp1252. When you use a unicode path, this gets correctly decoded to Unicode. Encoding the string u"08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\u0153ur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3" with cp1252 works. What is "filename" when you get the encode error? Is it a string or unicode? You shouldn't encode strings.

Comment: filename = u"C:\\Users\\Felix\\Music\\Muse\\The Resistance\\08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\x9cur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3" when doing filename.encode("cp1252"), so not a string.

Comment: Aha. Now we are getting somewhere. Notice how your unicode string that fails have '\x9c' in it. As you see above the correct unicode character for that is \u0153. So this unicode string is incorrect. How do you arrive to that filename? Is it before of after your example codes string manglings? In other words, what does `win32api.GetFullPathName(memoryBuffer.raw.split("\x00")[0])` return?

Comment: Both memoryBuffer.raw.split("\x00")[0] and win32api.GetFullPathName(memoryBuffer.raw.split("\x00")[0]) return "C:\\Users\\Felix\\Music\\Muse\\The Resistance\\08 - Muse - I Belong To You - Mon C\x9cur S'ouvre \xc0 Ta Voix.mp3". I guess this is because Winamp is using a different encoding that has "\x9c" as œ instead of "\u0153"?

Comment: @Fantasizer: No, \u0153 is *not* an encoding. That's the Unicode character. \x9c is an encoding of that Unicode character, and it's the encoding of that character in CP-1252. So you are, correctly, getting the string encoded in cp1252, as expected. So, next question: Why do you not return that string? Anyway, if you want to convert that string to Unicode, the correct code is: filename.decode('cp1252'), or unicode(filename, 'cp1252') would work too. That's it.